# Can we describe o-minimal theories in topological terms?

Tags: general-topology, model-theory

Talking about o-minimal theories in topological terms.

- Is there a standard way to talk about whether a given *structure* is o-minimal or not in topological terms?

I read about o-minimal theories the other day in *A Shorter Model Theory* in an exercise on page 29. The definition is compatible with the model-theoretic definition given in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory).

As stated in the Wikipedia article, a *theory* is o-minimal if and only if all of its *models* are o-minimal structures.

The first thing that I noticed is the definition appears to have a topological look and feel to it.

---

I tried to rephrase this definition in topological terms by making the definable sets *clopen* and generating a topology. But this construction fails for countable models where every singleton is nameable and reduces to a trivial topology where every subset is open and closed.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph, you can often avoid triviality by keeping track of the parameters allowed. Given a structure $\mathcal{A}=(A; ...)$ and a set $X\subseteq A$ let $\tau_X^\mathcal{A}$ be the topology on $A$ generated by the sets definable in $\mathcal{A}$ with parameters only from $X$. While $\tau_A^\mathcal{A}$ is discrete the coarser topologies corresponding to smaller parameter sets (e.g. $\tau_\emptyset$) may not be. On that note, we have by compactness that each structure $\mathcal{A}=(A;...)$ has an elementary extension $\mathcal{B}$ such that $\tau^\mathcal{B}_A$ is not discrete.

Comment: Here's one possible precise instance of your question, using the notion in my previous comment. Say that an expansion $\hat{\mathcal{R}}$ of $\mathcal{R}=(\mathbb{R};<,+,\times)$ is **restrained** iff for each $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ there is some $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $\tau_A^{\hat{\mathcal{R}}}=\tau_B^\mathcal{R}$. Basically, a restrained expansion doesn't add any topological behavior beyond some "parameter tweaking." Then: is there a restrained but non-o-minimal expansion of $\mathcal{R}$?

Comment: Actually, it's already unclear to me whether the obviously-non-o-minimal expansion $(\mathbb{R}; <,+,\times,\mathbb{Z})$ is restrained or not. It seems obvious to me that it *should* be, but I don't see a proof.

Comment: You're right that o-minimality has a topological feel to it, but usually what people think about is the ways in which o-minimality implies that definable sets are topologically trivial.

Comment: I went ahead and [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155603/does-naming-the-integers-in-mathbbr-times-change-the-definable-topolo?noredirect=1&lq=1) a related question.