# Does naming the integers in $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ change the "definable topologies" significantly?

Tags: general-topology, logic, model-theory

*This is motivated by [this recent question of Gregory Nisbet](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4155165/28111):*

For a structure $\mathcal{A}=(A;...)$ and a set $X\subseteq A$, let $\tau_X^\mathcal{A}$ be the topology on $A$ generated by sets definable in $\mathcal{A}$ with parameters from $X$. For example, $\tau^\mathcal{A}_A$ is always the discrete topology, although $\tau_\emptyset^\mathcal{A}$ need not be.

Now say that an expansion $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ is **restrained** iff for each $X\subseteq A$ there is some $Y\subseteq A$ with $\tau^\mathcal{B}_X=\tau^\mathcal{A}_Y$. Basically, a restrained expansion doesn't provide us with any new topological power except perhaps some "parameter juggling." I'm trying to get a sense of what the restrained expansions of a "tame" structure can look like, and the following seems a good starting point:

> Is $\mathcal{R}_\mathbb{Z}=(\mathbb{R};+,\times,\mathbb{Z})$ a restrained expansion of $\mathcal{R}=(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$?

After some thought, my guess is that the answer is **yes** (so in particular a restrained expansion of an o-minimal structure need not be o-minimal). However, I don't immediately see how to prove this, the general obstacle being that $X$ is usually **not** definable in the expansion of $\mathcal{A}$ by constants naming the elements of $X$. In fact it's not immediately clear to me whether $\mathcal{R}$ has *any* non-o-minimal restrained expansions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My intuition was way off and I missed a very easy argument.

Say that $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is **big** iff it contains a transcendence basis, and **small** iff it doesn't. The point is that $\tau_\emptyset^{\mathcal{R}_\mathbb{Z}}$ is too small to be $\tau^\mathcal{R}_A$ if $A$ is big and too big to be $\tau^\mathcal{R}_A$ if $A$ is small; the first point is basically trivial, and the second point comes from considering the set $\mathbb{I}$ of irrationals (which is clearly definable in $\mathcal{R}_\mathbb{Z}$, hence open in $\tau^{\mathcal{R}_\mathbb{Z}}_\emptyset$). In detail:

> **Lemma 1**: Suppose $A$ is uncountable. Then there is some real $\alpha\in A$ such that $\{\alpha\}$ is not open in $\tau_\emptyset^{\mathcal{R}_\mathbb{Z}}$, and so $\tau_\emptyset^{\mathcal{R}_\mathbb{Z}}\not=\tau^\mathcal{R}_A$.

*Proof*: Only countably many singletons can be open in $\tau^{\mathcal{R}_\mathbb{Z}}_\emptyset$, since the latter is second countable. $\quad\Box$

> **Lemma 2**: Suppose $A$ is small. Then $\mathbb{I}$ is not open in $\tau_A^{\mathcal{R}}$, and so $\tau_\emptyset^{\mathcal{R}_\mathbb{Z}}\not=\tau_A^\mathcal{R}$.

*Proof*: By smallness, let $\alpha$ be a real number not in the algebraic closure of $A$. If $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is definable in $\mathcal{R}$ using only parameters from $A$ and $\alpha\in D$, then by o-minimality of $\mathcal{R}$ and the transcendality assumption on $\alpha$ there must be some nontrivial open interval containing $\alpha$ which is a subset of $D$. But then $D\not\subseteq\mathbb{I}$. So $\mathbb{I}$ does not contain any of the basic opens of $\tau_A^\mathcal{R}$. $\quad\Box$

Since every big set is uncountable, we're done.

---

Some final remarks:

- The above is a very "coarse" argument, and applies to a wide range of unary relations; in particular, if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is countable then in order for $\mathcal{R}_A$ to be a restrained expansion of $\mathcal{R}$ the set $A$ (and everything we can build from it) must be extremely sparse.
- On the other hand, there are countably infinite sets which yield restrained expansions. For example, the expansion $\mathcal{R}_{2^\mathbb{Z}}$ is d-minimal: every definable set is a union of an open set and finitely many discrete sets *(see the bottom of page $2$ [here](https://people.math.osu.edu/miller.1987/tame_pre.pdf))*. This means that for any set of parameters $A$ we have $$\tau_A^{\mathcal{R}_{2^\mathbb{Z}}}=\tau^\mathcal{R}_{\mathit{Def}_A(\mathcal{R}_{2^\mathbb{Z}})},$$ where $\mathit{Def}_X(\mathcal{Y})$ is the set of elements of $\mathcal{Y}$ definable using parameters from $X$.
- Finally, every o-minimal expansion is restrained. This is because definable sets in o-minimal expansions of $(\mathbb{R};<)$ are quite simple: if $\mathcal{A}=(\mathbb{R};<,...)$ is o-minimal, then for each $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ the sets definable in $\mathcal{A}$ with parameters from $X$ are exactly those definable in $(\mathbb{R};<)$ with parameters from the $\mathcal{A}$-definable closure of $X$ (think about endpoints).

The second and third bulletpoints above were pointed out to me by James Hanson. It would be interesting to fully determine the restrained expansions of $\mathcal{R}$ (at least by unary relations), and this does not seem to me impossible: right off the bat we can rule out "topologically complicated" expansions, so we do have some hope of getting actual results. If anyone has any thoughts on this I'd love to hear them!

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, [this paper](https://people.math.osu.edu/miller.1987/tame_pre.pdf) says that for any $r > 0$, the expansion of the real field by a unary predicate for $r^\mathbb{Z}$ is d-minimal (meaning every definable set is the union of an open set and countably many topologically discrete sets). I think this gives a positive answer to your first follow-up question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said finitely many discrete sets.

Comment: @JamesHanson I've incorporated your observation. Do you know why Miller says "finitely many discrete sets?" Isn't the union of finitely many discrete sets ... still discrete?

Comment: The sets $\{0\}$ and $\{2^{-n}:n<\omega\}$ are both topologically discrete, but their union is not.

Comment: @JamesHanson Oh derp, I was thinking about discrete *closures*.

Comment: @JamesHanson OK, new question: is there a non-d-minimal restrained expansion? (I realize I keep moving the goalposts, but I'm increasingly interested in this.)

Comment: There was a new paper about d-minimal theories on arXiv in the last few days. I'm looking at it now, but there's an amusing coincidence which is that they also have a concept of *restrained* structures, although it is different.

Comment: $\mathcal R_{\mathbb Z}$ is interdefinable with the second-order arithmetic $(\mathbb P(\mathbb N),\mathbb N,+,\times,\in)$.