# Is there a topological definition of an interpretation from one structure to another in the sense of model theory?

Tags: general-topology, logic, model-theory

Is there a topological definition of an interpretation in the sense of model theory?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)) has a definition of an interpretation, reproduced below for convenience.

This definition seems really close to just the definition of continuity where the closed sets are precisely the definable sets.

> An **interpretation** of $M$ in $N$ **with parameters** (or **without parameters**, respectively) is a pair $(n,f)$ where $n$ is a natural number and $f$ is a surjective map from a subset of $N^n$ onto $M$ such that the $f$-preimage (more precisely the $f^{k}$-preimage) of every set $X \subset M^k$ definable in $M$ by a first-order formula without parameters is definable (in $N$) by a first-order formula with parameters (or without parameters, respectively). Since the value of n for an interpretation $(n,f)$ is often clear from context, the map $f$ itself is also called an interpretation.

For any given structure $M$ and a fixed arity $n$, however, we can define a topology $\tau^{(M, n)}$ as the topology generated by taking the definable-with-parameters sets as primitive closed sets. Let $M_n$ refer to $(M^n, \tau^{(M, n)})$.

The *continuous maps* $f : N_k \to M_n$ are precisely those that reflect definability, which lines up with the definition given by Wikipedia.

However, I'm not sure how to capture the surjectivity constraint and whether it has a topological characterization.

I'm also not sure whether this re-characterization using basic topological language is missing anything big that would make this re-characterization awkward or unworkable.

Comment: "The continuous maps ... are precisely those that reflect definability, which lines up with the definition given by Wikipedia." That's wrong: if you allow parameters in your definition, the topology you get is discrete since every co-singleton is definable with parameters.

Comment: The issue is that you're mixing up "open" and "basic open" - the continuous image of a basic open set is a *union* of basic opens, not necessarily a basic open, and so you can't conclude "preimage of definable is definable" as you want to.

Comment: In some sense this is what a geometric morphism between classifying toposes is: an interpretation of one theory in another.

Comment: @ZhenLin An important difference though is that then equality must be interpreted as equality, while an interpretation allows it to be interpreted as a definable equivalence relation.

Comment: @MarkKamsma In the classifying topos of a theory, we have quotients of definable equivalence relations, so I don't think it is a significant difference.

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh, of course, you are right. I was thinking of the syntactic categories, where this issue does arise. The embarrassing thing is that I actually made your comment precise (in the form of a functor) in a recent paper, see section 8 [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00153-022-00825-7). For the OP: this paper also provides a topological definition of interpretation, but not in the sense you are asking about, because it is expressed in terms of the type spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer:*

This question makes an incorrect assumption early on:

> The continuous maps [...] are precisely those that reflect definability, which lines up with the definition given by Wikipedia.

This is in fact **false**. Since every co-singleton is definable with parameters (trivially), the topology you suggest is discrete regardless of the structure in question, so *all* maps are continuous. Even if we disallow *(or otherwise [keep track of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155603/does-naming-the-integers-in-mathbbr-times-change-the-definable-topolo))* parameters the problem persists: in a structure in which every element is definable (such as $\mathbb{N}$), *every* self-map would be continuous in the relevant sense but most would not be self-interpretations.

The core issue is that you are conflating *basic open sets* and general open sets: all we get is "the preimage of a definable set is a *union of* definable sets," which is far from what is required. Continuity is simply too flexible a condition compared to "definability-reflection."